# How can I order a list of letters ("a","b","c",...,"z","aa","ab")? String#succ and <=> don't seem to play well together in this case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

One of my objects ('item') has an ID ('letter_id') in the format of "a", "b", ..., "aa", "ab", etc. To generate it I am using ruby's `String#succ` in an instance method like this:

```
def set_letter_id
  last = parent.items.all(:order => "letter_id ASC").last
  if last.nil?
    self.letter_id = 'a'
  else
    self.letter_id = last.letter_id.succ
  end
end
```

Now this works great until the 28th letter. The 27th will properly generate "**aa**", but then the value of `last` will always return the item with the letter_id of '**z**' because the ordering of the returned items doesn't follow the same rules as `String#succ`.

I found this out from a comment [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267810/string-range-comparison-problem/2267998#2267998) - but now I'm struggling to find a nice solution around this issue. The problem is basically this:

```
"aa".succ #=> "ab" - great, that's what I want.
"z"<=>"aa" #=> 1 - not so great, "z" should actually be less than "aa"
```

Obviously this isn't necessarily a bug, but it makes sorting and ordering a list of letter_ids in this format quite difficult. Has anyone encountered this and found a workaround, or any suggestions that I might try? Thanks!

Comment: Is it essential to use letter-based ids instead of guids or integers?

Comment: ya, it's essential for the leter-based IDs.

Comment: do not use `succ` for strings

Comment: It is strange indeed that, for instance, the range `'aa'..'aaa'` includes string `'cc'`, but that the range `'cc'..'aaa'` is empty. The book "Ruby Programming Language"'s section on ranges (3.5) says that ranges with string endpoints works because "the `String` class defines a `succ` method and `'a'.succ` is `'b'` and `'b'.succ` is `'c'`." No mention is made of the gotcha that you ran into: `'zz'.succ` is `'aaa'`, but `'zz'<=>'aaa'` is `-1`. One would think that the order that the `succ` method defines would be the same that the `<=>` method tests for, but apparently not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a solution in answers at link you've posted - you have to write own `<=>` in way to `sort_by{|i|[i.length,i]}`

```
irb> %w{a b c z aa ab zz aaa}.shuffle.sort_by { |i| [i.length,i] }
=> ["a", "b", "c", "z", "aa", "ab", "zz", "aaa"]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Nakilon I'm not sure how I missed that from the other thread. I'm going to give this a shot now.

Comment: Thanks again, sort_by{|i|[i.length,i]} was indeed the trick that I needed!

Comment: @Carter, yeah, this *trick* I've learned at SO. SO is a great teacher... sometimes...

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `<=>` method for your Item model to compare first by ID length, then by alphanumeric.

Something like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  # stuff

  def <=>(other)
    len_comp = self.letter_id.length <=> other.letter_id.length
    return len_comp if len_comp != 0
    self.letter_id <=> other.letter_id
  end
end
```

That way you first compare for shorter ID length (i.e., `"z"` before `"aa"`), then lexicographically.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of issue is exactly why some people discourage the use of `String#succ.`  It clashes with `Range`, `Object#to_a`, and others.

Anyway, you probably know this, but things like this might help...

```
>> t
=> ["x", "y", "z", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af", "ag"]

>> t.shuffle.sort_by { |e| "%3s" % [e] }
=> ["x", "y", "z", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af", "ag"]
```

You could even renormalize this way and dispense with `sort_by`.

Comment: Wouldn't this solution (eventually) have problems scaling?